# Read-only fields in SQLite3 database table?

Tags: database, sqlite, constraints

I'm a beginner when it comes to databases and have been reading through the SQLite3 documentation. However, I can't find the answer to the following:

Is it possible to create a SQLite3 database table that has some read-only fields (i.e. not the whole of the table is read-only)?. I know I can stop people writing to the fields via some extra code, but I was wondering if can define a constraint or something similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to prevent updates of specific columns:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ro_columns
BEFORE UPDATE OF col1, col2 ON mytable
BEGIN
    SELECT raise(abort, 'don''t do this!');
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, constraints [cannot be added after table creation in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html);

> It is not possible to rename a column, remove a column, or add or
>   remove constraints from a table.

In other words, no, you cannot make a column read only using a constraint, since creating the table with the (`CHECK`) constraint would make it impossible to add the read only values to the table in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to rename the table and create a view in its place. You can then use `INSTEAD OF` triggers to update the table instead.

See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example table, with a `readonly` field, that when set to non-zero, the row becomes read-only.

```
CREATE TABLE test (data TEXT, readonly INTEGER);
```

Here is the trigger that forbides UPDATE of `data` when `readonly` is non-zero:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_ro BEFORE UPDATE OF data ON test WHEN OLD.readonly != 0
BEGIN
    SELECT raise(fail, "Read-only data");
END;
```